# React.js: Passing a callback to a child component and removing a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a link to the source https://github.com/bengrunfeld/gae-react-flux-todos/tree/master/src/js

In the React tutorial, it shows how to pass a callback to a child component, which can then go ahead and use it.

Say you want to generate a list of Todos, but pass each Todo a callback so that if the `delete` button is hit on that todo, it will call the function `removeTodo` in its parent (`TodoList`) that will remove it from the DOM.

So the problem I'm running into is that in the following example, because of the scope of `this.props.data.map`, I can't pass `this.removeTodo` to `<Todo>`. It errors out as `undefined` if you try it.

Secondly, even if I could, I am not sure how to go about removing the Todo from the DOM, as I don't have access to a mutable version of `state` inside `TodoList` - it is only available as an immutable `this.props`. If I could alter `state`, I could then call `setState`, which would fire a render, which would remove the items from the list.

So how would you solve this?

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
  removeTodo: function(todo) {
    // Remove Todo
    // Change the state
    // Re-render with setState();
  },
  render:function(){
    var todoNodes = this.props.data.map(function(todo) {
      return (
        <Todo key={todo.id} id={todo.id} onRemoveTodo={this.removeTodo}>
          {todo.title}
        </Todo>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="todoList">
        {todoNodes}
      </div>
    )
  }
var Todo = React.createClass({
  onDeleteClick: function(todo){
    AppActions.deleteTodo({id: todo.target.className});

    // Call the `removeTodo` function in `TodoList` (parent) here!
    // this.props.onRemoveTodo
  },
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div><p>{this.props.children} - <a className={this.props.id} onClick={this.onDeleteClick}>delete</a></p></div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you following the flux architecture? Can you add the code for `AppActions`?

Comment: @DeepakPrasanna Yes, I'm following the Flux architecture. If I add it in here, the code block will be too big, but here's a link to my actions file: [https://github.com/bengrunfeld/gae-react-flux-todos/blob/master/src/js/actions/app-actions.js](https://github.com/bengrunfeld/gae-react-flux-todos/blob/master/src/js/actions/app-actions.js)

Comment: Try adding `AppStore.emitChange(AppConstants.CHANGE_EVENT);` on line https://github.com/bengrunfeld/gae-react-flux-todos/blob/master/src/js/stores/app-store.js#L74

Comment: Did you add it? It worked?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I'm still trying. I have to remove the todo from `_todoItems`. I think it will work. If it does, I will add a comment ASAP and upvote all of yours.

Comment: @DeepakPrasanna - I had to run a jQuery `grep` on the list of all `_todoItems` to remove the deleted Todo. Then I fired the change event and the page updated beautifully. Thank you!! You are a scholar and a gentleman. =)

Comment: I have made an answer on the comment I posted. Please accept it if you feel generous. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, since you are following the Flux architecture, you need to emit the `CHANGE_EVENT` after you delete the todo item in `deleteTodo` which is present in the store.

```
  deleteTodo: function(todo) {
    this.deleteTodoOnServer(todo).done(function(result){

      //DELETE your the TodoItem here

      AppStore.emitChange(AppConstants.CHANGE_EVENT);
      return;
    }).fail(function(result){
      console.log('fail');
      // return 'error in deleteTodoOnServer Ajax call: ' + result;
    });
  },
```